# Neo4j's Cypher query language - reducing nodes in a match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Relatively new to Neo4j. I realize the way I originally posted this it was too ambiguous. Below is hopefully a better explanation.

```
//Subgraph 1
Create (p1:Person {name: 'Person1'}) 
Create (p2:Person {name: 'Person2'})
Create (a1:Address {street: 'Suspicious'})
Create (p1)-[:Resides]->(a1)
Create (p2)-[:Resides]->(a1)

//Subgraph 2
Create (p3:Person {name: 'Person3'})
Create (p4:Person {name: 'Person4'})
Create (a2:Address {street: 'Double'})
Create (p3)-[:Resides]->(a2)
Create (p4)-[:Resides]->(a2)
Create (p3)-[:Knows]->(p4)

//Subgraph 3
Create (p5:Person {name: 'Person5'})
Create (a3:Address {street: 'Single'})
Create (p5)-[:Resides]->(a3)
```

What I would like to write is a query to detect the following:
- All addresses (and people) that have 2 or more People residing there that do not know each other.

This means that only Subgraph1 should be found.

Subgraph2 would not be found because there are 2 people that reside there but they know each other.

Subgraph3 would not be found because there is only 1 person residing there.

Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: You really should be using labels. Since you don't have labels here, any queries solutions we could offer (that aren't making assumptions on labels) will have to check the pattern on all possible nodes, which isn't efficient. Using a :Home node, for example, will ensure the query will start at :Home nodes using the label index, and will cut down on execution time.

Comment: I have changed the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Cypher query should work:

```
MATCH (n1)-[:RESIDES_AT]->()<-[:RESIDES_AT]-(n2)
WHERE NOT exists((n1)-[:KNOWS]-(n2))
RETURN n1, n2
```

start by matching on nodes that have a `RESIDES_AT` relationship to the same node, then filter out nodes that have a `KNOWS` relationship.

Comment: Good answer, though it may be useful to have `AND id(n1) < id(n2)` to prevent matching to the same nodes with the order flipped.

Comment: Or indeed match a node to itself, so also `AND n1 <> n2`may be needed.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could put patterns in NOT exists(), which means you could do the inverse also.